# Scale one normally distributed column to the distribution of another normally distributed column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy, statistics

I have two normally distributed columns. Col_1 ~ N(10.599704,2.187732) and Col_2 ~ N(9.628111,1.120925). Is there anyway to scale the values of column 1 so that they look like they are distributed like the values in column 2 in python? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the values to z-scores (which are essentially normally distributed with mean 0 and stdev 1), and then just scale them up to match an arbitrary mean/stdev

```
In [85]: l = np.random.normal(10, 2, 100)

In [86]: l.mean(), l.std()
Out[86]: (10.21841407055716, 1.6444921910870982)

In [87]: import scipy.stats as ss

In [88]: l2 = ss.zscore(l) * 100 + 5000

In [89]: l2.mean(), l2.std()
Out[89]: (5000.000000000001, 99.99999999999996)
```

If you don't want the sample z-score since that's using the sample mean and stdev, you could calculate it as `(l - 10) / 2` instead.